# How to sort X Axis(By dates from DatePicker) in LineChart?

Tags: sorting, date, javafx, datepicker, linechart

I have my LineChart but it isn't work well because I want to sort the x axis by date which user of my app sets earlier in DatePicker.

At the moment my linechart looks like this

[LineChart in my app - unsorted X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPFAg.png)

Here is the code:

```
void initLineChart()
{

    //defining a series
    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String,Number>();
    lineChart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.X_AXIS); // not works

    String date = new String();
    int numb;
    String value = new String();

    ShowDreamHistoryController.save(); //saving my app to the file
    ShowDreamHistoryController.loadDreamAtStart(); //load my app from the file
    for (int i = 0; i < ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.size(); i++) {
        date = ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.get(i).getDate().toString(); // get dates 
        value = ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.get(i).getHours(); // values in Y axis
        System.out.println(value); // info just for me 
        if(value != null)
        {
        numb = Integer.valueOf(value);
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>(date, numb));
        }
    }

    lineChart.getData().add(series);
}
```

As I said, i want my X axis to sort by date. Can someone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Only this:

' lineChart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.X_AXIS); // not works'

I am the beginner and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: How did you called the constructor of LineChart?

Comment: It is only this 'initLineChart()' in class 'HomeScreenController'. I made everything in SceneBuilder. Do you want to see more code ? or the screen of my app >

Comment: and yes, I am using the JDK 8 (jdk1.8.0_45)

Comment: Sorting of the X-axis seems not supported, when the X-axis is of type CategoryAxis. It worked only with NumberAxis. I have tested it with [these examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm) and jdk1.8.0_66.

Comment: When I add exactly the same Code as these from [this site](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm) I have nothing, I mean that I do not have any line on my chart. Any ideas ?